# Getting Location updates even if i am in same place for long

Tags: android, location, google-api-client

I am using `GoogleApiClient` for getting current `location` as well as periodic `location` updates.
I have set requestLocation parameter as below:

```
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters
```

and make a request like this :

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

So my question is when i am not moving for 10 meters then it also called and give me `location`.
I want perfect `location` updation like google as i have required for the same.
And when i move to some distance it gives locations for number of times.
I have to check in my application that if user is continuously moving 
and if user move/pass some distance then i have to check and do the necessary things.

Thank you.

Comment: can you show the code where you create the location request?

Comment: @Midas Lefko i am creating location request in onConnected() method.

Comment: Are you using [LocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(float)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)) when you create the location request?

Comment: See i am testing it right now and it gives me distance like 19.0, 102.0 in meters for the same place.

Comment: ok.i will add this line and let you know...thanks

Comment: i have added this line 
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10); 
but it still gives me distance like 85.97 meter for the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locations can be very inaccurate (which is what you are experiencing with a stationary phone having a distances of 10m - 100m). To overcome this, check the accuracy of the new location. If the accuracy is 40m and the distance from the lastLocation is 50m you know that there has been movement. However, if the accuracy is 100m, then a distance of 50m won't tell you for certain that there has been movement.

Therefore, if accuracy of your location updates is more important than frequency, you might want to check the accuracy of your Location before you use it. For example:

```
private Location lastGoodLocation = null;

// Other methods

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

    if (lastGoodLocation == null || lastGoodLocation.distanceTo(loc) > loc.getAccuracy()) {
         lastGoodLocation = loc;
         // do something with loc
    }
}
```

You also might want to consider other [strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate) when using Location update.

Comment: yes i can achieve by this but the problem is i got distance like 10 to 100 meters even if my device is in same place.
I have tested in nexus 5 device.

Comment: I have already accepted it because of your elaborate explanation.
I will also make it correct if it will work like i want.
Thank you :)

Comment: How it takes accuracy ?
On which base it takes a accuracy value ?

Comment: You can check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()) out.

Comment: Now this work perfectly for distance 300 meter and time interval 30 sec.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check out [TripTracker](https://github.com/jcs/triptracker) on github. It will help you.

Comment: Thank you Jadav Lalit. I will check and let you know if i achieved the same or not.